# Do (the restrictions of) continuous maps (to the rationals) form a Borel set?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, measure-theory, descriptive-set-theory

Consider, within the Polish space $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{Q}$ (with product topology), the subset of all those maps that can be extended to a continuous map on all of $\mathbb{R}$.

It's easy to see that this set is co-analytic. But is it sharply so, or is it actually a Borel set?

Comment: If anyone can think of a helpful extra tag, pls feel free to add it.

Comment: I've added some common tags that are reasonable approximations to the subject matter in order to increase visibility.

Comment: Forgive me if I'm missing something obvious, but why is this set coanalytic?

Comment: Not easy to write it down very shortly, but the gist is this: If it's not continuous, there exists a Cauchy sequence of rationals for which the 'image-sequence' doesn't converge in R. (If there are two sequences converging to the same point, and the image-sequences both converge, but to different limits, you can take x1, y1, x2, y2, etc.)  I hope that is a bit clear as a sketch?

Comment: BTW, thanks for adding the extra tags

Comment: Okay, I understand that that an element of $\Bbb R^{\Bbb Q}$ is not continuously extendible iff we can find the right Cauchy sequences in $\Bbb Q$ for that function.  So, why does this mean that the set of "non-continuous" elements of $\Bbb R^{\Bbb Q}$ is the continuous image of a Polish space?

Comment: And you're welcome!

Comment: Consider the subset of $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}^\omega$ consisting of pairs (f, (x_n)) where the (x_n) is a Cauchy sequence and f(x_n) is not. This is a Borel set. Project this set.

Comment: Ah, that's where the gap is; I assumed that the set you're projecting had to be closed, perhaps I misremembered the definition of an analytic set though.

Comment: Every Borel set is the continuous image of a closed one... (standard result, somewhere in Kechris, but also in Moschovakis).

Comment: Ah, that's good to know... seems like I'm not going to be much help here afterall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's Borel.  Let's call the desired set $C$.

Note that a function $f : \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{R}$ has a continuous extension to $\mathbb{R}$ iff $f$ is uniformly continuous on bounded sets.  (For the forward direction, a continuous function is uniformly continuous on relatively compact sets.  For the backward direction, use the fact that uniformly continuous functions map Cauchy sequences to Cauchy sequences.)  Or, equivalently, if it's uniformly continuous on each interval $[-N,N] \cap \mathbb{Q}$.

Now to write out the definition, $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[-N,N]$ iff for all $\epsilon$ (without loss of generality, assume $\epsilon$ is of the form $1/n$) there exists $\delta$ (also of the form $1/m$) such that whenever $p,q \in [-N,N] \cap \mathbb{Q}$ with $|p-q| < 1/m = \delta$, we have $|f(p) - f(q)| < 1/n = \epsilon$.

Let $U_{p,q,n} = \{f \in \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{Q} : |f(p) - f(q)| < 1/n\}$.  By definition of the product topology and continuity of subtraction, $U_{p,q,n}$ is open.  Let's also let $A_{N,m} = \{(p,q) \in ([-N,N] \cap \mathbb{Q})^2 : |p-q| < 1/m\} \subset \mathbb{Q}^2$ which is countable.  Then we can write the desired set $C$ as
$$C = \bigcap_{N=1}^\infty \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \bigcup_{m=1}^\infty \bigcap_{(p,q) \in A_{N,m}} U_{p,q,n}.$$

So $C$ is (at worst) $G_{\delta \sigma \delta}$.  If I am counting correctly I think this is $\mathbf{\Pi}^0_4$.

One uses tricks like this a lot in probability theory, where we deal with stochastic processes, which correspond to probability measures on function spaces.  You very often need to show that the set of all functions with some property is measurable, and it usually turns out to be Borel of pretty low rank.  Proofs often go like this, where you exploit some analysis fact to get a convenient characterization of the property, and then use a little bit of care to only have to quantify over countable sets.

---

Alternatively, if you'd rather use fancier theorems: the space $C(\mathbb{R})$ of all continuous functions $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is Polish, with the topology of uniform convergence on compact sets (UOCS).  A sequence converging UOCS converges pointwise at each rational, so the map $\Phi : C(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{Q}}$ defined by $\Phi(f) = f|_{\mathbb{Q}}$ is continuous; in particular it's Borel.  It's also injective (two continuous functions which agree on the rationals must agree everywhere), and its image is the desired set $C$.  Now in Polish spaces, the image of a Borel set under an *injective* Borel function is always Borel; you can find this theorem in descriptive set theory books.

(Alternatively alternatively, this argument showed $C$ is analytic, and you already knew it is coanalytic, so it must be Borel.  But now we're really using nuclear weapons to kill tiny arthropods.)

Comment: Thanks! Great answer (because it's more generally applicable).  Is there a similar 'technique' to prove sharpness of such results? In particular, in our case, is there a way to see that it can't be $\Delta_4^0$, or $\Pi_3^0$?

Comment: @Anonymous: I think such arguments usually come from the Baire category theorem, like the way you prove that $\mathbb{Q}$ is not $G_\delta$ in $\mathbb{R}$.  If I'm not mistaken, $C$ is meager and dense, so likewise it cannot be $G_\delta$.  But I don't immediately see how to go further - it's not something that people in my line of work usually care too much about :-)

Comment: Actually, $C$ seems to be $\Pi_3^0$, as in your characterization, the open set $|f(p) - f(q)| \lt 1/n$ can be replaced with the closed condition $|f(p) - f(q)|$ $=<$ $1/n$, and intersections of closed sets are closed, etc.

Comment: A typical way to locate a Borel set at a given level of Borel hierarchy is by constructing Wadge reductions to an appropriate complete set. See for example http://www.math.wisc.edu/~akumar/BOREL_GROUPS.pdf

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, but just a "too long for a comment" additional remark to Nate's answer and Anonymous' last comment.

The set $C$ is indeed $\mathbf\Pi_3^0$, and in fact it is a *true* $\mathbf\Pi_3^0$ set; that is, $C$ is not $\mathbf\Sigma_3^0$.

To see this, consider the map $\Phi:\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}\to \mathbb R^{\mathbb Q}$ defined as follows. With any sequence $\mathbf a=(a_n)\in\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$, you associate the function $f_{\mathbf a}$ defined by $f_{\mathbf a}(0)=0$, $f_{\mathbf a}(1/n)=a_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$, and $f_{\mathbf a}$ is "affine" on each $[\frac1{n+1},\frac1n]\cap\mathbb Q$ and equal to $0$ for $t\leq 0$ and to $a_1$ for $t\geq 1$. If I'm not mistaken, the map $\Phi$ is continuous from $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ into $\mathbb R^{\mathbb Q}$. Moreover, $\Phi^{-1}(C)=c_0:=\{ \mathbf a=(a_n);\; a_n\to 0\}$, which is well known to be a true $\mathbf\Pi_3^0$ subset of $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$. Hence, $C$ is a true $\mathbf\Pi_3^0$ set.